# help me understand PHP's preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have this link:
http://mysite/myfolder/it/my-keywords.html and want to replace /it/ with /es/ (2 letter country codes)

I could `explode()` with "/" delimiter but would like to understand if preg_replace would be better.

tried:

```
preg_replace("/\/([a-z]{2})/\/", $link, $country);
```

**EDIT**
answer:

```
preg_replace("/\/[a-z]{2}\//", "/$country/", $link);
```

Comment: This is more straightforward if you chose an alternate regex delimiter (you can then avoid the escaping, which clearly tripped you up a little): `preg_replace("@/[a-z]{2}/@", $link, $country);`

Comment: Other delimiter. Thanks for the tip Frank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preg_replace is like a swiss army knife. preg rather than ereg means it uses perl compatible regular expressions. It matches first param (regex), replaces with second param (string) in third param (string).

Regular expressions are optimized for efficiency by using search tree cutoff techniques etc... so are generally efficient alternative method.

This should do what you want.

```
preg_replace("/\/it\//","/es/","http://mysite/myfolder/it/my-keywords.html")
```

Comment: Thanks Billy for showing me the correct regex with escaping the slashes. I think you better use double quotes btw...

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace is useful if you only know a part of string that you want to match, but others parts are variable. In your case the /it/ folder is already unique enough so that a static replacement would work. Use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) instead:

```
$url = str_replace("/it/", "/es/", $url);
```

Comment: @FFish; Learn re and related php functions. So, for re cases, in future, won't ask one more duplicated.

Comment: hi, actually the link is dynamic. I need something like preg_replace("/\/([a-z]{2})/\/", $link, $country);

Comment: @FFish; If you already have the appropriate regex, what exactly is your question about it?